# How to achieve this perticular AND and OR logic in apache rewritecond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to do a Rewritecond like:

if (A AND B) OR (C AND D) OR (E AND F)
do ReWriteRule

As far as know, OR has more priority than AND, so if I do

```
rewritecond A     
rewritecond B [or]
rewritecond C 
rewritecond D [or]
rewritecond E 
rewritecond F
RewriteRule xxxx
```

It probably will do 
A AND (B OR C) AND (D OR E) AND F instead, which is not what i want..
How should i achieve the first order?

Thanks!!!

/Lorin

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want. You just have to write the same `RewriteRule xxxx` 3 times

```
RewriteCond A     
RewriteCond B
RewriteRule xxxx

RewriteCond C 
RewriteCond D
RewriteRule xxxx

RewriteCond E 
RewriteCond F
RewriteRule xxxx
```

Comment: m..I was trying to avoid that, since i have many similar things that will result a long settings in the config file. but you are right, that's probably the way. Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK it is the only way. The issue is purely aesthetic (nobody likes big conf files) but Apache doesn't mind anyway